# Nginx redirect requests to sub-domains that do not exist to custom 404 page when wild card A record is set?

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to capture all requests to arbitrary sub-domains which do not have a virtual host setup, and redirect to a custom 404 page in nginx? I will have a wild card A record setup *.example.com and all our users will have a sub-domain username.example.com. If someone enters a sub-domain which does not exist how can I redirect to a custom 404 page rather than have it resolve since wild card is setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - though I'm not sure what you mean by "rather than have it resolve" - hopefully you don't mean preventing DNS resolution, as that's not possible from your web server.

You'll want something like this:

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80 default_server;
  error_page 404 http://your.site.com/prettyerrorpage.html;
  return 404;
}
```

Comment: No what I meant was that I think with wild card A records with some configurations between the server and DNS that people going to random sub-domains end up at your home page